# The war package hosted in the tomcat container would create a new process when it run?

Tags: java, tomcat

I put the war package in the tomcat with path Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps , when I run the war package in web browser, it would create a new Java.exe\Javawe.exe process, or it still share the same process tomcat.exe with the tomcat? Someone told me it would share the same process tomcat.exe with tomcat, someone told me it would create a new Java runtime process Java.exe\Javaw.exe.

If the war package share the same process tomcat.exe, and if the war has memory leak issue, then we should capture the core dump for the tomcat.exe , right?

Comment: The `war` package does not _do_ **anything**. Tomcat unpacks the `war` and executes to code. There is a single JVM - Tomcat's.

Comment: @Boris , thank you. so it means all of the war hosted in the tomcat container would shae the same process tomcat.exe.?  we know we can monitor the process tomcat.exe by the JVisualVM , however if we can monitor a single war package? based on the following URL , it seems we can achieve it by the following commends with the parameter value "YourJavaApp" , is it?
===========
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333 \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
     YourJavaApp

https://visualvm.java.net/jmx_connections.html

Comment: You cannot monitor a single war. The options you have pasted enable JMX for a JVM; you then attach your tool (VisualVM JConsole etc) to the specified port. You don't need to do any of that if Tomcat is running as your user on your computer - you can just attach to the PID as with any other Java process.

Comment: @ Boris, I found no options from the JVisualVM  to attach to the process by the pid in Windows, can you show me how to do it?

Comment: If VisualVM can see the process it will be listed on the LHS of the interface in the "Applications" pane under "Local".

Comment: @Boris, sometimes we often cannot see the some Java processes.

Comment: Then they are not running as your user and you do not have permission to access them. In that case you need to use JMX. I have covered all this in my comments above.